# Как сохранить изображение с сайта на диск?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, web-apps

Программу для работы с сайтом пишу с помощью библиотеки для C# WatiN.

Встал такой вопрос: как сохранить изображение с сайта себе на диск?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду фото ? 

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace ForHash
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/m/a/madwind7/100000294.jpg");
            client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg" );
            Console.WriteLine("Картинка скачана");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее было бы так:

```
    //Загружаем изображение на диск
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string path = "тут путь к картинке";
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(path), "Папка_в_которой_будет_размещен_файл\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));//System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path) - получает имя файла
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);//В случае успешного завершения загрузки файла выполняем указанный метод
       ...
       ...
//Метод, который будет выполнен в случае успешного завершения
void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Картинка успешно загружена!");
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не подходит способ, т.к. изображение генерируется с помощью PHP при каждом обращении к нему, то есть нужно как то получить картинку ту которая уже отобразилась на страничке.

Comment: Ааа... ну так это совсем другое дело. Тогда нужно парсить саму html-страничку. Рекомендую для этого библиотеку HtmlAgilityPack. Если что, то могу расписать подробнее, что к чему.